# C++ I want fscanf to ignore newline characters but not other whitespace characters

Tags: c++, file-io, scanf, newline

In my program I want to read data from a file character by character and store them somewhere but I want to ignore newline characters. Ive been trying to find a solution to this all day. When I leave a space before the %c it ignore all whitespaces when I use stuff like `fscanf(fp, "%*[\n]", ch);` I cant get it to continue reading from the next line. Or it only reads last line for some reason. Can someone please help me?

Comment: You are probably best off reading character-by character from the input, splitting the data as you please. Perhaps you can put filtered input in a character buffer and use sscanf() from there to free you from re-inventing the wheel e.g. when parsing numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is supposed to be a C++ question how about iostream/boost::...::filter_istream solution ? It gives you the full input capacity of iostreams (number pasring etc.)

```
 #include <boost/iostreams/device/file.hpp>
 #include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
 #include <boost/iostreams/concepts.hpp>

 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>

 static const int NL = 0xa;
 class nl_input_filter : public boost::iostreams::input_filter {
 public:
     template<typename Source>
     int get(Source& src) {
         int c;
         while ((c = boost::iostreams::get(src)) != EOF && c !=   boost::iostreams::WOULD_BLOCK) {
            if(c != NL)
                break;
        }
        return c;
    }
 };

 int main()
 {
     std::ifstream fi("/tmp/bla");
     boost::iostreams::filtering_istream in;
     std::string s;
     in.push(nl_input_filter());
     in.push(fi);
    while ( in >> s )
    {
        std::cerr << s << std::endl;
    }
}
```